# Passing parameters to url scheme salesforce1://

Tags: salesforce1-app, url, parameters, mobile-url-scheme, deep-linking

I am connecting to salesforce1 (mobile app) from another mobile native app using the salesforce1:// mobile scheme, as per the overview [document](https://na7.my.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce1_url_schemes_ios.pdf).

Instead of using standard objects and pages I am passing to the vf page as this document indicates that we can pass "apex" as the object, as per regular url structure.

My Visualforce page accepts and needs some url parameters that the calling app is passing, these parameters are recieved correctly by the vf page when on desktop but not through the salesforce1:// mobile scheme.

**Is there any special handling required to pass url parameters through the salesforce1:// url scheme?**

I am passing as below:

```
salesforce1://apex/myvfpage?parameter=value&hello=world
```

Comment: we can use `'{!$CurrentPage.parameters.searchText}'` at js side in vf page.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87698/parameter-passing-issue-in-salesforce1-app