# Parameter passing issue in salesforce1 app

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, url, parameters

I am passing a parameter from vf page A to page B through URL and getting it on controller of B.It is working when I tried in browser.I created a app for salesforce1 and when I run it ,I am not able to get parameter from URL. 
Please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: try to get the parameter on load of page. using javascript. `$CurrentPage.parameters.parameter_name`.  bcz after onload url changed in SF1

Comment: I am having this same issue and when trying to get the parameter on load in javascript it's not there either. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `'{!$CurrentPage.parameters.searchText}'` at javascript code and get url parameter in SF1 also. we can keep this script on top of page. so before url changes in SF1 , we get the required result.